# Fixed orientation on android genymotion not working

Tags: android, genymotion, android-orientation

I have read on many sites that all i need to do to make orientation change impossible on my android activity is just put this on my manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.karutakanji.ModoCasual"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tela_inicial_multiplayer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        </activity>
```

But when i try my activity on Genymotion and a 2560 x 1600 device, the activity is still flipping to landscape orientation(it happens right at the start of the activity). Is there something else i need to do to make orientation change impossible to my activity? Is it only a Genymotion bug? What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

There must be something else interfering with your manifest settings. I just tested it and I can't switch genymotion to landscape within my activity. If I start my activity when I am in landscape, genymotion directly changes to portrait as expected.

My guess: Whatever you do in your activity in onCreate() might interfere or overwrite it.

*edit*: the `configChanges` are not important. `screenOrientation` is the attribute you need to "restrict" it to that orientation.

Comment: strangely enough, this bug doesn't happen on my 1024 x 600 real-life tablet. The only strange things i do on OnCreate() of my class is:super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 enableDebugLog(ENABLE_DEBUG, TAG);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_modo_casual);

Comment: Can you share your genymotion device settings and the genymotion version you are using? Maybe "just" a bug in genymotion.

Comment: i am using genymotion 2.5.2 and i am emulating a Google Nexus 10 - 4.3 - API 18 - 2560 x 1600(120dpi)

Answer (score 0):

solved it: it was just aGenymotion problem. I just had to emulate the device on fullscreen mode to make the bug disappear ^^